# css - Footer is not expanding

Tags: css, footer

Im very new to css and I still find hard to understand some concepts especially positioning.
Anyway, my problem is that my when I set `position: relative;` of the container and my footer `position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;`  the footer became small. It had the same width as the container which is supposed to be before I placed those codes. I did it because I want my footer to be at the most bottom part of the container.

Below is the screen shot:

[image]

The maroon is the footer.

In my footer I don't use div but instead I use html element `<footer>`.

My css codes:

```
div#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #C9C9C9;
    position: relative;
}

footer {
    background-color: #340B09;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: can you just set width:100% on footer?

Comment: Be very careful about setting heights using inflexible units such as px.  It's fine if what it is containing is also fixed (such as images) but it gets messy with text.  Some browsers allow you to override your font-size choices and they'll end up with text overflowing your containers, potentially making it unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I properly solved it by declaring width of footer to 980px; When I tried 1000px it became wider than the container because after researching I found out that mozilla and webkit doesn't include padding in the width.

Answer (score 5):

Add width: 1000px; to your footer

Answer (score 2):

Check this, if that may help you
https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/css-positioning.html

i will also encourage, you to have firebug installed in your browser

Also above the footer, add some div container, give it some height.. so that footer will stay at bottom. don't use positioning explicitly... since you are new to this.

Get yourself some time, you will be there on top of it..with CSS position :- )

Answer (score 2):

Is it necessary for you to use relative and absolute positioning ? I'm asking since it has one drawback which is that the layout of the page will not be the same as always for all the different sizes of the screen.

Since you wanted to display footer at the bottom of the container, so here it can be done in this way.

```
<style type='text/css'>

body{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: black;
}

#inbody{           /* main page */
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  height: 1170px;
}

#container{         /*container */
  padding: 10px;        
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;       
  height: 1130px;   
  background-color: orange;         
}

#header{            /* header */
  margin-left: 168px;
  height: 51px;
}

#midbody{           /* middle body */
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 999px;
}

#footer{            /* footer */
  padding: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
}

</style>
```

Moreover you can change colors of every part to see the changes. Also use inspect element which shows the HTML and CSS of the web page. Also for the box model concept try experimenting the metrics in the inspect element.

Answer (score 1):

You are using;

```
footer {
    background-color: #340B09;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
}
```

If `footer` is some ID or Class, it should be defined in CSS like `#footer` or `.footer` and no problem if you are using html5 element `footer`.

If you want to stretch an element to fill container, use `width: 100%`. Add this to your footer if footer is inside your `container`. Otherwise it will stretch to screen.

Comment: he is using the html5 element 'footer'.